# Multiply each element of an array by another array?

Tags: matrix

I would like to multiply an array by each element of another array, and am having a lot of trouble finding a built-in or automated method of doing.

Here is an example of what I'd like to achieve:

```
a = 0.5;
b = 4.0;

mat = {{0, 1}, {a, b}};
Rmat = RandomInteger[10, {4, 4}]
m11 = mat[[1, 1]]*Rmat;
m12 = mat[[1, 2]]*Rmat;
m21 = mat[[2, 1]]*Rmat;
m22 = mat[[2, 2]]*Rmat;

fmat = ArrayFlatten[{{m11, m12}, {m21, m22}}]
```

As you can see, the first matrix `mat` is multiplied by each individual element of `Rmat`.
I feel like this should be easy, but I'm not finding a built-in function that works?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

```
ArrayFlatten[Outer[Times, mat, Rmat]]
```

Comment: Those both work thanks!

Comment: @rasher...good old Outer,+1

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
ArrayFlatten[Map[Rmat*# &, mat, {2}]]
```

Answer (score 4):

It was apparently missed by the other posters that `KroneckerProduct[]` is built-in:

```
KroneckerProduct[mat, Rmat]
```

Comment: Yep. Forgot it....

Comment: J.M Could you help me question if you have time now? Please see [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dMbxc.png) and [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SLOYn.png)

Comment: @Shutao, not sure what those pictures are supposed to be. Why not write a proper question instead of a comment?

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. I think this small question could be solved in the [chatting room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/wolfram-mathematica).

Comment: Maybe  [this picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Apn2B.png) can express what I need.